# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression for jpa pagination ${users.totalPages != 0}

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to make a pagination of the data present in the database. I have an exception that is triggered on `users.totalPages != 0`. But when I debug, it returns the number of pages that goes from 1 to 5:userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage=Page 1 of 5 containing  UserDto instances

> Controller method to get all users in database

```java
@GetMapping("/allUsers")
    public ModelAndView getUsersList(ModelAndView modelAndView, UserSearchParameters userSearchParameters) {

          // Evaluate page size. If requeste parameter is null, return initial page size
        int selectedPageSize = userSearchParameters.getPageSize().orElse(InitialPagingSizes.INITIAL_PAGE_SIZE);
        
        // Evaluate page. If requested parameter is null or less than 0 (to prevent exception), return initial size.
        // Otherwise, return value of param. decreased by 1.
        int selectedPage = (userSearchParameters.getPage().orElse(0) < 1) ? InitialPagingSizes.INITIAL_PAGE
                : (userSearchParameters.getPage().get() - 1);

        PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(selectedPage, selectedPageSize, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "id"));
        UserSearchResult userSearchResult = new UserSearchResult();

        // Empty search parameters
        if (!userSearchParameters.getPropertyValue().isPresent()
                || userSearchParameters.getPropertyValue().get().isEmpty()) 
            userSearchResult.setUserDtoPage(userService.listUserByPage(pageRequest));
        
         //Search queries
        else {
            userFinder.setUserSearchParameters(userSearchParameters);
            userSearchResult = userFinder.searchUsersByProperty(pageRequest);

            if(userSearchResult.isHasNumberFormatException())
               return userFinder.searchResultHasNumberFormatException(modelAndView);
            

            if (userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage().getTotalElements() == 0) 
                modelAndView = userFinder.searchResultIsEmpty(modelAndView, pageRequest);
            

            modelAndView.addObject("usersProperty", userSearchParameters.getUsersProperty().get());
            modelAndView.addObject("propertyValue", userSearchParameters.getPropertyValue().get());
        }

        Pager pager = new Pager(userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage().getTotalPages(), userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage()
                .getNumber(), InitialPagingSizes.getButtonsToShow(), userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage().getTotalElements());
        
        modelAndView.addObject("pager", pager);
        modelAndView.addObject("users", userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage());
        log.debug("userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage="+ userSearchResult.getUserDtoPage());
        modelAndView.addObject("selectedPageSize", selectedPageSize);
        modelAndView.addObject("pageSizes", InitialPagingSizes.PAGE_SIZES);
        modelAndView = new ModelAndView("users/allUsers");

        return modelAndView;

    }
```

> User result search class with setter

```
 @Data
public class UserSearchResult {
    private Page<UserDto> userDtoPage;
    private boolean hasNumberFormatException;

    public UserSearchResult() {
        super();
    }

    public UserSearchResult(Page<UserDto> userPage, boolean numberFormatException) {
        super();
        this.userDtoPage = userPage;
        this.hasNumberFormatException = numberFormatException;
    }

    
    //region find methods
    //==============================================================================================
    public void setUserDtoPage(Page<UserDto> findAllPageable) {

        this.userDtoPage = findAllPageable;
    }

    public Page<UserDto> getUserDtoPage() {
        return userDtoPage;
    }

    public boolean isNumberFormatException() {

        return hasNumberFormatException;
    }

}

<!--Paging-->
        <div id="paging-section" class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">

            <!--Page size dropdown-->
            <div class="form-group col-md-1"
                th:if="${users.totalPages != 0}">

                <!--Get pageSizesToShow-->
                <div hidden=true id="pageSizesToShow"
                    th:attr="data-pageSizesToShow = ${pager.pageSizesToShowInJSON}"></div>

                <select class="form-control pagination" id="pageSizeSelect">
                    <option th:each="pageSize : ${pageSizes}" th:text="${pageSize}"
                        th:value="${pageSize}"
                        th:selected="${pageSize} == ${selectedPageSize}"></option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

> console log
> 15-01-2022 00:11:10.490 ERROR org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "users/allUsers": Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "users.totalPages != 0" (template: "users/allUsers" - line 207, col 6)
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "users.totalPages != 0" (template: "users/allUsers" - line 207, col 6)
> at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:292) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.VariableExpression.executeVariableExpression(VariableExpression.java:166) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.SimpleExpression.executeSimple(SimpleExpression.java:66) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:109) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:138) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Expression.execute(Expression.java:125) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.StandardIfTagProcessor.isVisible(StandardIfTagProcessor.java:59) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> at org.thymeleaf.standard.processor.AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractStandardConditionalVisibilityTagProcessor.java:61) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'totalPages' cannot be found on null
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:213) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:104) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:51) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:406) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:92) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpNE.getValueInternal(OpNE.java:43) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.OpNE.getValueInternal(OpNE.java:33) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:112) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:337) ~[spring-expression-5.3.12.jar:5.3.12]
> at org.thymeleaf.spring5.expression.SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(SPELVariableExpressionEvaluator.java:265) ~[thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
> ... 121 common frames omitted

> Please help me to display my view with all data.

Comment: From your log `3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE] Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'totalPages' cannot be found on null at` make sure your `users` is set correctly.

Comment: Hello Ratul, yes users is correctly set, and i add UserSearchParameters class , you can see it.